# how to rotate my gray scale image properly?

Tags: python, image-processing, image-manipulation, image-preprocessing, image-augmentation

I wanna augment my grayscale images by rotating and flipping them. however, when I rotate them they get doubled. I don't know how to explain it so I've uploaded a sample image.
[you can see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6rgH.jpg)

my code:

## Load glioma images

```
train_glioma_img = []

for path in glioma_train_path:
    img = imread(path)
    if len(img.shape) > 2: # incase it has 3 dim __ making sure that all of the images are gray scale
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        image = np.array(img).astype(np.float64)
        train_glioma_img.append(image)
    else:
        image = np.array(img).astype(np.float64)
        train_glioma_img.append(image)


train_glioma_x = np.array(train_glioma_img)
train_glioma_x.shape
```

## # Augment them

```
final_train_data = []

number_of_added_images = int((2000-len(glioma_train_path))/2)
a = random.sample(range(0, len(glioma_train_path)), number_of_added_images)
b = [i for i in range(0, len(glioma_train_path)) if i not in set(a)]

for i in tqdm(range(train_glioma_x.shape[0])):
    final_train_data.append(train_glioma_x[i])

for i in tqdm(range(number_of_added_images)):
    final_train_data.append(rotate(train_glioma_x[a[i]], angle=random.randint(20, 100), mode = 'wrap'))

for i in tqdm(range(number_of_added_images)):
    final_train_data.append(np.fliplr(rotate(train_glioma_x[b[i]], angle=random.randint(20, 100), mode = 'wrap')))
```

## To show single image

```
image = np.array(final_train_data[1990])
hi = np.max(image)
lo = np.min(image)
image = (((image - lo)/(hi-lo))*255).astype(np.uint8)
im = Image.fromarray(image)
im
```

Comment: You appear to have included one image to show us what happens when you try to rotate an image, but you don't say if that is the *"before"* or *"after"* image, nor show us the other.